# How to insert data into a table from another table with the possibility of duplicate keys

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, query-optimization, on-duplicate-key

I'm attempting to write a conditional query that inserts new rows into a table from data from another table, but if the PK already exists for that row, to update it instead. I came across `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`, but can only find examples that work with inserted values rather than data obtained from an inner select statement. Here is an example to illustrate what I'm talking about:

```
INSERT INTO SCHEMA1.TABLE1 T1
  (T1.ID,
   T1.COLUMN1,
   T1.COLUMN2)
SELECT T2.ID,
       T2.COLUMN1,
       T2.COLUMN2
FROM SCHEMA2.TABLE2 T2
WHERE T2.COLUMN3 = ?)
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE T1.COLUMN1 = T2.COLUMN1;
```

For some reason, the syntax of the above does not work. The only thing that I can gather from the Oracle docs is that `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` can only be used with `VALUES` -- not a nested `SELECT` query.

Comment: That's what the [MERGE](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/statements_9016.htm) statement is for.

Comment: I think you've been looking at [MySQL documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17952_01/refman-5.0-en/insert-on-duplicate.html). That syntax isn't valid in [Oracle RDBMS](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/statements_9014.htm). But yes, that's what merge is for.

Comment: Merge worked perfectly! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to mustaccio and Alex Poole, here is the solution:

```
MERGE INTO SCHEMA1.TABLE1 T1 USING
(SELECT ID,
   COLUMN1,
   COLUMN2
 FROM SCHEMA2.TABLE2
 WHERE COLUMN3 = ?) T2
ON (T1.ID = T2.ID)
WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET
  T1.COLUMN1 = T2.COLUMN1,
  T1.COLUMN2 = T2.COLUMN2
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN INSERT (
  T1.ID,
  T1.COLUMN1,
  T1.COLUMN2
VALUES (
  T2.ID,
  T2.COLUMN1,
  T2.COLUMN2);
```

Answer (score 0):

> Just an alternative whcih you can use instead of MERGE if you have
>   ORACLE version 11 or more. We have some specific HINTS from oracle 11g
>   onwards which are used to ignore duplicate values on unique INDEX.
>   Below snippet is a very small but descriptive example which you can
>   incorporate hope this helps.

```
-- Table creation with Primary key as SR_NO
CREATE TABLE DUP_CHECK_KEY
(
SR_NO NUMBER PRIMARY KEY,
NAME VARCHAR2(100 CHAR)
);

Table created

-- Inserting random data in the first go
INSERT INTO DUP_CHECK_KEY
SELECT LEVEL,LEVEL||'Av' FROM dual 
CONNECT BY level < 10;

10 rows inserted.

--Again inserting same data with 2 more unique rows to be inserted.
INSERT /*+ ignore_row_on_dupkey_index(DUP_CHECK_KEY,SYS_C00145520) */ INTO DUP_CHECK_KEY
SELECT LEVEL,LEVEL||'Av' FROM dual 
CONNECT BY level < 12;

2 rows inserted.
```

> Since we have 10 duplicate key values it has ignored the dup values
>   and inserted only 2 unique values.

Comment: That doesn't update existing values though, as merge does, and as the question states is required.

Comment: Ohh my bad. I have overlooked the second part